# How can I perform a command on my server so it keeps running when my Wifi drops

Tags: ssh, tar

I need to log into my server and tar up a huge directory of about 150GB, but I need to run the command so when I get back home, it's still running.

can I just SSH into my server from my laptop, run the tar command, and head home? how do I check the status of the tar when I get back home, etc...

thank you

Comment: Oh, are all these, surprisingly similar, questions related to your home system?

Comment: I had a life crisis, my development team screwed me over, and I had to transfer everything over immediately to a new server. sorry... That's why so many questions...

Comment: When i say screwed me over, I mean I paid this dev team 50k, and they left everything unfinished, and I have to switch from the current server to the new company fast....

Comment: @mattdm: You created [sysadmin-basics] tag for this single question? You should have a look at the [related discussion on MSF](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/490/fundamentals-tag) and the *purpose* of the [tag creation privs](http://serverfault.com/privileges/create-tags).

Comment: @jscott -- looks consistent with all that, yes. Note that it is more specific than just "beginner".

Comment: @mattdm I fail to read anything *"more specific"* in the tag. A [[basics](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/basics)] tag already exists.  As SF is a syadmin-oriented site, prefixing *"basics"* with *"sysadmin-"* adds little value in the new tag.

Comment: *shrug*. Retag it to "basics" then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could first execute [`screen`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/) and then run the command within screen.

or

You could run the command using [`nohup`](http://ss64.com/bash/nohup.html)

I would prefer `screen` as you can resume the session and see the progress..
When you get home run `screen -r` and it will "reattach" the session you left on your laptop.

Comment: You might be interested in researching tmux (http://tmux.sourceforge.net/). Personally, I love screen. But looking into tmux transition has been on my to-do list for a while now.

Comment: Ah yes, I am waiting for http://serverfault.com/questions/208501/does-tmux-have-all-the-features-that-screen-has-and-those-screen-is-missing to have some answers to decide on tmux

Comment: I just saw your question pop up on my RSS feed. Creepy.

Answer (score 3):

You need [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), which lets you start one or more shell sessions and then detach from them and reattach to them.  If you've never heard of it before, run and read the web page now!  It's a fantastically useful tool for just the situation you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just run your command using `at` or `cron`. `at` is easy but it is not always installed by default, but it should be available from your package manager. Install it then run it like so.

```
at HH:MM (time 2 minutes or so in future)
```

it will open a shell, type you commands there

```
date >/tmp/out 2>&1
tar [your options] >>/tmp/out 2>>&1
date >>/tmp/out 2>>&1
```

press control-D and start `/etc/init.d/atd`. Logoff and check back later. Look at `/tmp/out` for output log.

Or you could use `cron`